# How can I delete a window.history state?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

Using the HTML5 `window.history` API, I can control the navigation pretty well on my web app.

The app currently has two states: `selectDate` (1) and `enterDetails` (2).

When the app loads, I `replaceState` and set a `popState` listener:

```
history.replaceState({stage:"selectDate",...},...);
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    that.toStage(event.state.stage);
};
```

When a date is selected and the app moves to stage 2 I push state 2 onto the stack:

```
history.pushState({stage:"enterDetails",...},...);
```

This state is replaced anytime details change so they are saved in the history.

There are three ways to leave stage 2:

- save (AJAX submit)
- cancel
- back button

The back button is handled by the `popstate` listener. The cancel button *pushes* stage 1 so that the user can go back to the details they were entering the back button. These both work well.

The save button should revert back to stage 1 *and not allow the user to navigate back to the details page* (since they already submitted). Basical, y it should make the history stack be length = 1.

But there doesn't seem to be a `history.delete()`, or `history.merge()`. The best I can do is a `history.replaceState(stage1)` which leaves the history stack as: `["selectDate","selectDate"]`.

How do I get rid of one layer?

**Edit:**

Thought of something else, but it doesn't work either.

```
history.back(); //moves history to the correct position
location.href = "#foo"; // successfully removes ability to go 'forward', 
                       // but also adds another layer to the history stack
```

This leaves the history stack as `["selectDate","selectDate#foo"]`.

So, as an alternative, is there a way to remove the 'forward' history without pushing a new state?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You may have moved on by now, but... as far as I know there's no way to delete a history entry (or state).

One option I've been looking into is to handle the history yourself in JavaScript and use the `window.history` object as a carrier of sorts.

Basically, when the page first loads you create your custom history object (we'll go with an array here, but use whatever makes sense for your situation), then do your initial `pushState`.  I would pass your custom history object as the state object, as it may come in handy if you also need to handle users navigating away from your app and coming back later.

```
var myHistory = [];

function pageLoad() {
    window.history.pushState(myHistory, "<name>", "<url>");

    //Load page data.
}
```

Now when you navigate, you add to your own history object (or don't - the history is now in your hands!) and use `replaceState` to keep the browser out of the loop.

```
function nav_to_details() {
    myHistory.push("page_im_on_now");
    window.history.replaceState(myHistory, "<name>", "<url>");

    //Load page data.
}
```

When the user navigates backwards, they'll be hitting your "base" state (your state object will be null) and you can handle the navigation according to your custom history object.  Afterward, you do another pushState.

```
function on_popState() {
    // Note that some browsers fire popState on initial load,
    // so you should check your state object and handle things accordingly.
    // (I did not do that in these examples!)

    if (myHistory.length > 0) {
        var pg = myHistory.pop();
        window.history.pushState(myHistory, "<name>", "<url>");

        //Load page data for "pg".
    } else {
        //No "history" - let them exit or keep them in the app.
    }
}
```

The user will never be able to navigate forward using their browser buttons because they are always on the newest page.

From the browser's perspective, every time they go "back", they've immediately pushed forward again.

From the user's perspective, they're able to navigate backwards through the pages but not forward (basically simulating the smartphone "page stack" model).

From the developer's perspective, you now have a high level of control over how the user navigates through your application, while still allowing them to use the familiar navigation buttons on their browser.  You can add/remove items from anywhere in the history chain as you please.  If you use objects in your history array, you can track extra information about the pages as well (like field contents and whatnot).

If you need to handle user-initiated navigation (like the user changing the URL in a hash-based navigation scheme), then you might use a slightly different approach like...

```
var myHistory = [];

function pageLoad() {
    // When the user first hits your page...
    // Check the state to see what's going on.

    if (window.history.state === null) {
        // If the state is null, this is a NEW navigation,
        //    the user has navigated to your page directly (not using back/forward).

        // First we establish a "back" page to catch backward navigation.
        window.history.replaceState(
            { isBackPage: true },
            "<back>",
            "<back>"
        );

        // Then push an "app" page on top of that - this is where the user will sit.
        // (As browsers vary, it might be safer to put this in a short setTimeout).
        window.history.pushState(
            { isBackPage: false },
            "<name>",
            "<url>"
        );

        // We also need to start our history tracking.
        myHistory.push("<whatever>");

        return;
    }

    // If the state is NOT null, then the user is returning to our app via history navigation.

    // (Load up the page based on the last entry of myHistory here)

    if (window.history.state.isBackPage) {
        // If the user came into our app via the back page,
        //     you can either push them forward one more step or just use pushState as above.

        window.history.go(1);
        // or window.history.pushState({ isBackPage: false }, "<name>", "<url>");
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        // Add our popstate event listener - doing it here should remove
        //     the issue of dealing with the browser firing it on initial page load.
        window.addEventListener("popstate", on_popstate);
    }, 100);
}

function on_popstate(e) {
    if (e.state === null) {
        // If there's no state at all, then the user must have navigated to a new hash.

        // <Look at what they've done, maybe by reading the hash from the URL>
        // <Change/load the new page and push it onto the myHistory stack>
        // <Alternatively, ignore their navigation attempt by NOT loading anything new or adding to myHistory>

        // Undo what they've done (as far as navigation) by kicking them backwards to the "app" page
        window.history.go(-1);

        // Optionally, you can throw another replaceState in here, e.g. if you want to change the visible URL.
        // This would also prevent them from using the "forward" button to return to the new hash.
        window.history.replaceState(
            { isBackPage: false },
            "<new name>",
            "<new url>"
        );
    } else {
        if (e.state.isBackPage) {
            // If there is state and it's the 'back' page...

            if (myHistory.length > 0) {
                // Pull/load the page from our custom history...
                var pg = myHistory.pop();
                // <load/render/whatever>

                // And push them to our "app" page again
                window.history.pushState(
                    { isBackPage: false },
                    "<name>",
                    "<url>"
                );
            } else {
                // No more history - let them exit or keep them in the app.
            }
        }

        // Implied 'else' here - if there is state and it's NOT the 'back' page
        //     then we can ignore it since we're already on the page we want.
        //     (This is the case when we push the user back with window.history.go(-1) above)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. That is rather more elegant than what I've been using as a workaround.

Comment: What to do when a user is accustomed to this behaviour, then navigates a few times building up a state, then navigates to external site, then navigates back and I assume the history of all the app's navigation is now gone and the back button will be last on the heap.

Comment: The state pushed by history.pushState will be available when they come back (also if they close or refresh their browser).  Some browsers will fire a popstate event on page load, but others do not (Firefox for example).  But you can always read history.state directly.  If you're not making use of the history.state object, you would need to use another means of persisting your state (like localStorage).  history.state is persisted automatically as part of the browsing history.

Comment: How to push the current page into myHistory as you said `myHistory.push("page_im_in_now")`? Tell me an example please

Comment: Nice solution! A minor problem could be the inability to go back more than one step at a time. Browser's history will show always just two entries for such an application.

Comment: @Andrej - absolutely true on not being able to go back multiple steps via the browser!  I haven't come up with any _good_ solutions for that.  I mean you could possibly push a new "back" page for every navigation and figure out how far back the user went if they hit one, but I think it would get messy when you modify the custom history stack.  There may be a better option, but I haven't needed it for any of my own uses so I haven't gone very far down that particular rabbit hole.  :)

Comment: The solution seemed very promising. It assumes that any popstate event can only be caused by a back navigation. This simplifies lot's of things. Promising. But it completely breaks down when hash-changes are involved. Any hash change will also trigger the popstate event, and we are left with no way of knowing whether this is a backward navigation or a forward navigation or neither of both: it could also be a manually changed hash.

Comment: Hi @FatihCoşkun - the examples do assume that popstate is only from backward navigation, but you can use the ‘state’ object of the popstate event object to determine what’s going on.  For example, when you push/replace your state, add something like ‘isBackState=true’ to the object.  Then when your popstate event fires, check for that property - if it’s there, you know it’s a back navigation.  If not, it’s a hash change (which you can then do a replaceState to get back where you were).  On mobile, will give more detail later this evening.

Comment: Thanks for replying after so much time @MikeB. I sure hope that there is a simple solution, but I could not wrap my head around it yet. The problem I see with your last suggestion is that the popstate event's state property is not the previous state, but instead it is the current state. When the user navigates back as the first thing on the page, our state object will not be there anymore.

Comment: I think the solution must involve putting pushed hashes into our own history stack as well. So that we know their back-logic is already handled for us by the browser.

Comment: Yeah, basically there are three possible pages:  [back]--[app]--[hash], and we want to keep them in the [app] page.  If they go to [back], we handle that and push them to [app] again.  If they go to [hash] by changing the URL hash, we handle that and push them to [app] again.  Added some example code to the answer at the bottom, hope that helps!  (Note that it does not handle persisting the `myHistory` object, but you could make that part of the state or save it to local storage or whatever you want to do really.)

Comment: Yes that sounds like it might work. I will try it on monday. Our app does not use hash for coding states. We use it only for linking to anchors within the page. And we don't want the loose the functionality of having such hash links in the back history.  As far as I understand we will need to get rid of the hash in the native history and manage them in our own history. Whenever the user navigates back to a hash in our history, we will need to pushState(state, title, hash) as in your suggestion but with the hash that we just popped from our own history.

Comment: If you're only using the hashes for anchors and you don't need to modify their behavior (adding/removing them from history _programmatically_), then I think you can mostly just let the browser handle it.  so you can have [back]--[hash0]--[hash1]--[hash2].  User can be on any [hash] page, the only page with special behavior is [back].  You will probably need to add some state to each new hash page with `replaceState` but that would strictly be for use in the `pageLoad` function to detect a user entering your site via browser history - it wouldn't need to deal with the custom `myHistory` object.

Comment: The problem I was facing was that I didn't have a way to determine whether a popstate event was a back that I need to handle myself or a hash change. This can be solved by the isBack property in the first state object. Another problem is that after x changed hashes there might come a situation in which we want to push some state ourself. Like [back][hash0][hash1][state0]. We cannot solve that without dealing with hashes ourself, can we? But it seems possible with the more complicated solution that you suggested.

Comment: Ahh... yeah, letting the browser handle hashes doesn't work once you put new pages after it.  So yeah, that should all work with the [back][app][hash] model and always keeping the user on [app].  The hash changes would be treated just like a separate page (as far as navigation/history), but your page/nav logic can determine if you actually need to render a new page or just scroll to an anchor.

Comment: I have come across a new problem. In your latest suggestion, in the popstate handler: 

// If they have moved to a new hash page, Undo what they've done by kicking them backwards to the app...... The problem is, this invocation of go(-1) will trigger another popstate event, which will re-invoke the handler. I will need to somehow disable the handler during this case. What's more, invoking go(-1) will not clear the forward history. The actual solution will need to invoke go(-2) and then re-push the app state, to clear the forward history. The solution I can think of is rather complex.

Comment: For solving the problems mentioned in previous comment, in my current approach this is the setup of native history: [reset][back][app]. When a hash change happens, I will push the hash onto my internal history and navigate to the reset state via go(-3). The reset state will reset the native history.

Comment: Updated the on_popstate example.  For the `history.go(-1)` issue, we can basically just ignore the popstate event when we're on the [app] page (if the event has state, and it's _not_ the back page, then it's the [app] page).  For disabling the forward button, `replaceState` should work.  (If calling replaceState after history.go(-1) doesn't work, you could instead move it into the popstate event that was otherwise being ignored (popstate on [app]).)  Another option is to leave it and just ignore it (if they nav to the same hash they're already on, kick them back without modifying anything).

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to delete or read the past history.

You could try going around it by emulating history in your own memory and calling `history.pushState` everytime window `popstate` event is emitted (which is proposed by [the currently accepted Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29227026/1860149)), but it has a lot of disadvantages that will result in even worse UX than not supporting the browser history at all in your dynamic web app, because:

- popstate event can happen when user goes back ~2-3 states to the past
- popstate event can happen when user goes forward

So even if you try going around it by building virtual history, it's very likely that it can also lead into a situation where you have blank history states (to which going back/forward does nothing), or where that going back/forward skips some of your history states totally.

Comment: Another issue when trying to make back/forward work, is that when the state is pushed, the title gets saved to History. Now when a user uses View History or right-clicks the back button, the user can get taken to a page that they were not expecting if you try to do anything smart.

Comment: Some of these issues are pretty trivial to solve. Indexing the pushed state is a good start - something like a `stateDepth` property that is incremented in the decorated `pushState`, alongside a `prevState`. If `prevState.stateDepth === 4`, and you're now at `state.stateDepth === 2`, you've got a good idea of how far you are back

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution:

```
var ismobilescreen = $(window).width() < 480;
var backhistory_pushed = false;

$('.editbtn').click( function()
{
    // push to browser history, so back button will close the editor 
    // and not navigate away from site
    if (ismobilescreen && !backhistory_pushed)
    {
        window.history.pushState('forward', null, window.location);
        backhistory_pushed = true;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) 
{
    $(window).on('popstate', function() 
    {
        if (ismobilescreen && backhistory_pushed && $('.editor').is(':visible'))
        {
            // hide editor window (we initiate a click on the cancel button)
            $('.editor:visible .cancelbtn').click();
            backhistory_pushed = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Results in:

1. User opens editor DIV, the history state is saved.
2. User hits back button, history state is taken into account.
3. Users stays on page!
4. Instead of navigating back, the editor DIV is closed.

One issue: If you use a "Cancel" button on your DIV and this hides the editor, then the user has to click the mobile's back button two times to go back to the previous URL.

To solve this problem you can call `window.history.back();` to remove the history entry by yourself which actually **deletes the state** as requested.

For example:

```
$('.btn-cancel').click( function() 
{
    if (ismobilescreen && backhistory_pushed)
    {
        window.history.back();              
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could push a URL into the history that holds an anchor, e.g. `#editor` and then push to history or not if the anchor exists in the recent URL or not.