# How can I reset browser's navigation history in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to clear browser navigation history  in angular2 so that after user get navigated to particular page (page of my interest) the shouldn't be able to go back or forward by clicking browser back or next button.......

For now I tried importing Angular2 Location like this

```
 import {Location} from "angular2/router";
```

and using it like this to prevent navigation

```
 this._location.replaceState('/'); //clear browser navigation history and reset it to root /
 this._router.navigateByUrl('/home');
```

Note: assume Location and Router are properly injected

But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this is supported by the browser. See [JS - window.history - Delete a state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028297/js-window-history-delete-a-state)

There was an issue created recently to allow to pass a custom `HistoryStrategy` that should allow you to manage how and when an URL is pushed to the history.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3481

Comment: thanks... I realized that i had to implement my own custom HistoryStrategy  by injecting window object and implementing window.onpopstate event... thanks will do it latter...