# Remove parameter from url using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html5-history

I wan to remove parameter from URL without reloading or refreshing page.

I used below code for that, and it's working fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    window.history.pushState("", "", "/" );
});
```

But problem is if I click on browser back button I can see parameters in url.

Comment: Because it is in the `array-like` state...Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028297/js-window-history-delete-a-state

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because [`pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState%28%29_method) adds a new entry to the browser history.

Use [`replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_replaceState%28%29_method) instead, to replace the current entry.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
    window.history.replaceState("", "", "/" );
});
```