# How do I load new URLs sequentially to cover up browser history using vanilla Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a domestic violence site for women who are in abusive relationships and want help to get out. I need to create a "Safe Exit" button on the page to allow a user to quickly exit the site in case their abuser walks into the room and sees them looking for help.

The desired functionality is:

1. Click the button to take you away from current page.
2. Hit 20ish believable pages(urls) that will be added to browser history so that it pushes the Domestic Violence site way down in the history and almost renders the back button useless.
3. It should never actually load those "dummy urls" and eventually land the user on a page like Google or YouTube.

**EXAMPLE OF DESIRED FUNCTIONALITY**(red button at page bottom):  http://www.ncadv.org/

Ideally this would all happen in a matter of 2 or 3 seconds since time is of the essence for someone in a domestic violence situation.  Vanilla Javascript is preferable, jQuery will also work.

Thank you for your help, a lot of people will be grateful for you input.

Comment: It should (and can) happen within a second. But you can replace the current address using `window.history` API though. Just read on that topic. ( and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028297/js-window-history-delete-a-state) )

Comment: Thank you Karel. Have you looked at the way the button works on the ncadv.org?  From what i've gleaned from the window.history API, it won't allow me to "flood" the browser history with relevant page titles.  Try that button on the site I referenced above, watch the address bar, then check your history.  I'm curious to see if that changes your thoughts at all.

Answer (score 0):

That the site you show as an example is using HTTP Referrer..

What you can do is to have an anchor that links to the same URL as in the example site.

So in your HTML:

`<a href="http://abconlinenews.info/localnews.php">Go to safety</a>`

If you want to use different URLs then you'd have to create your own pages with each containing a referrer to a page that doesn't exist.

Something like:

```
function trigger() {
        setTimeout("setPage();",10);
}
function setPage() {
    window.location="/nextPage.php";          
}
```

and HTML like:

```
  <body onload="trigger();">
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
        <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
  </body>
```

Comment: So, i don't want to create my own pages on the domain because the idea is that it will take them away from the domestic violence site, disguising the fact that they were looking for help from their abuser.  So I need to load up their web history somehow within the same window so that it: A) doesn't show recently closed windows.  B) Additional history makes their browsing for help much less noticeable at first glance if the abuser tries to click the back button or look at the recent history.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ugh .. That's true.. Sorry long day here at work.. 
I totally forgot that the user should go away from the site. In that case it's not possible without owning the external pages yourself. because the host site needs to have something that will redirect from it. The example you have given works because the those sites are interconnected in that way that each link refers to another.

Comment: Thank you!  So tell me if I'm looking at this the right way:
1. Host a few cheap(semi-believable domains)
2. Create a few semi-believable file names on each domain
3. Each page will have a simple script on it that checks the referrer and redirects to the next dummy page file if the referrer is what it's expecting until finally the last redirect will take them to Google.
If one of those dummy page files are accessed directly from the browser history, it redirects to an actual page that looks relevant to that dummy domain(weather4cast.info > weather.com). Help with the individual scripts?