# Pop a pushed history state history.pushState

Tags: javascript, browser-history, pushstate

I am using history.pushState to manipulate the browser history, Is there a way to undo/pop a particular pushed state.

Let's say I came from google.com to myPage.com. After an ajax call I do pushState,

```
window.history.pushState({}, "SUMMARY", "/summary.html");
```

Now after some more ajax calls, Is there a way to delete the earlier pushed state so the back button takes me to google.com instead of myPage.com

Edit: After the first ajax call I am pushing the state so i can go back earlier state, but I want to remove this functionality if another ajax call is made .

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028297/js-window-history-delete-a-state

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceState`

```
window.history.replaceState({}, "", "https://google.com");
```

Comment: How would you know where the user came from ? . Google.com was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

When you are loading content using AJAX call then instead of `pushState` you can use `replaceState` . `replaceState` does not manipulate the browser's history, it simply replaces the current URL in the address bar. Upon hitting the back button you'll find that we don't return to the replaced URL but instead you'll go back to whatever page we were on before.

In your case you can use

```
window.history.replaceState({}, "SUMMARY", "/summary.html");
```

Comment: I was pushing a state so i can undo the ajax call on back button , but replace state won't change the back button functionality.

Comment: If you use `replaceState` then why you need to undo it?