# Javascript History back error how to delete history back

Tags: javascript

can't we use `window.history.back();` twice time in same web browser

Lets say I have use `window.history.back()` where it does store how to delete it from a browser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JS - window.history - Delete a state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028297/js-window-history-delete-a-state)

Answer (score 0):

You may have moved on by now, but... as far as I know there's no way to delete a history entry (or state).

One option I've been looking into is to handle the history yourself in JavaScript and use the window.history object as a carrier of sorts.

Basically, when the page first loads you create your custom history object (we'll go with an array here, but use whatever makes sense for your situation), then do your initial pushState. I would pass your custom history object as the state object, as it may come in handy if you also need to handle users navigating away from your app and coming back later.

```
var myHistory = [];

function pageLoad() {
    window.history.pushState(myHistory, "<name>", "<url>");

    //Load page data.
}
```

Now when you navigate, you add to your own history object (or don't - the history is now in your hands!) and use replaceState to keep the browser out of the loop.

```
function nav_to_details() {
    myHistory.push("page_im_on_now");
    window.history.replaceState(myHistory, "<name>", "<url>");

    //Load page data.
}
```

When the user navigates backwards, they'll be hitting your "base" state (your state object will be null) and you can handle the navigation according to your custom history object. Afterward, you do another pushState.

```
function on_popState() {
    // Note that some browsers fire popState on initial load,
    // so you should check your state object and handle things accordingly.
    // (I did not do that in these examples!)

    if (myHistory.length > 0) {
        var pg = myHistory.pop();
        window.history.pushState(myHistory, "<name>", "<url>");

        //Load page data for "pg".
    } else {
        //No "history" - let them exit or keep them in the app.
    }
}
```

The user will never be able to navigate forward using their browser buttons because they are always on the newest page.

From the browser's perspective, every time they go "back", they've immediately pushed forward again.

From the user's perspective, they're able to navigate backwards through the pages but not forward (basically simulating the smartphone "page stack" model).

From the developer's perspective, you now have a high level of control over how the user navigates through your application, while still allowing them to use the familiar navigation buttons on their browser. You can add/remove items from anywhere in the history chain as you please. If you use objects in your history array, you can track extra information about the pages as well (like field contents and whatnot).

You could also extend the idea to handle forward navigation. You would need 3 pages - a "back" handler page, a "forward" handler page, and a "rest" page in between them where the user will typically be. You would then need to traverse back and forth along your history object instead of simply pushing/popping the items