# how to clear location state in react?

Tags: reactjs, web, frontend, react-dom

```
const navigate = useNavigate()
      <div
          className="back-page"
          onClick={() =>
            navigate(back_page, {
              state: { is_returning: new Date() },
            })
          }
        >
          <Button />
        </div>
```

When the APP navigates to `back_page`, it will retrieve the value for `is_returning`. And then it should clear this state. How do I clear this state?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `react-router-dom`, it's using [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) by default, so basically [there's no way to delete history state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028297/how-can-i-delete-a-window-history-state). However, you could replace current route with the same route but an empty state. Translate that back into `react-router-dom`, that's

```js
navigate(currentUrl, {
    replace: true
})
```